# How can I get the usernames in the account?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm making a VB.Net application which connects to a MySql database.
My application has many Accounts, and each account has several Users. I want to show this information, but the application just shows  the first user of each account.

This is the code:

```
Public Function id(Label2 As String) As Double
    Using connection = Getconnection()
        connection.Open()
        Using commandid = New MySqlCommand
            commandid.Connection = connection
            commandid.CommandText = "SELECT *FROM player.player
            Where player.account_id=" & testString & V
            Dim read = commandid.ExecuteReader
            If read.HasRows Then
                While read.Read
                    ActivateUser.namecharacter = read.GetString(2)
                    ActivateUser.job = read.GetString(3)
                End While
                read.Dispose()
                Return True
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(" no ")
                Return False
            End If
            connection.Close()
            connection.Dispose()
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

How can I fix this to show all the users in the account?

Comment: Please note, this is SQLi vulnerable, use parameters at all times.

Comment: There is only **one** `ActivateUser` object. This code sets ever result to that same object in quick succession, so the we only see the last one. You need to redesign your user interface to create a place to show all the users, or cycle through them. We can't help you do that, since we can't see your form or screen designs.

Comment: You probably need a Junction table for a many to many solution. Each account in one table. Each user in another table. Then a third table with AccountID and UserID.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and answers, you really found the solution, I am grateful to you thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just create you connection in the method where you use it. Get rid of `GetConnection` just use a class level variable for the connection string.

Don't open a connection until directly before you use it.

You can include the command in the same using block by adding a comma at the end of the first line. Commands also need to be disposed. The command constructor can take the `CommandText` and the `Connection` as parameters.

What datatype is `account_id` in the database? I am going to guess it is a string type. Is `V` a variable or is it meant to be the string "V"? I am going to guess a hardcoded string. Where does `testString` come from? I am going to guess `Label2` (terrible non-descriptive name) is `teststring`.

**Never** concatenate strings for you sql. **Always** use parameters.

A reader also needs to be closed and disposed so use Using blocks. The whole idea of accessing the database is to get in and out as quickly as possible. Don't set properties of `ActivateUser` and never show a message box. The user could have gone to lunch and your connection is left flapping in the breeze.

You have the datatype of your function as `Double` but your return statements have `Boolean`s. Won't work.

It is not necessary to close and dispose the connection. The `End Using` does that.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Public Function id(Label2 As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
            commandid As New MySqlCommand("SELECT *FROM player Where account_id= @TestString;", connection)
        commandid.Parameters.Add("@TestString", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label2 & "V"
        connection.Open()
        Using reader = commandid.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Then back in the User Interface code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = id(Label2.Text)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ActivateUser.namecharacter = dt(0)(2).ToString
        ActivateUser.job = dt(0)(3).ToString
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(" no ")
    End If
End Sub
```

This makes a good separation of from your database code.

Comment: Still only shows the one user, but this is definitely the first and most important stuff to address.